# Are community ads ever served?

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, publicity

So [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) are now activated, and at the time of this writing we have 4 ads meeting the criteria for being served on the sidebar:

[image: current "active" ads]

The [stats page](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/6539) is showing each ad's score, creation date and total/average number of clicks, but not the number of times it was served, so we don't really have a way of actually seeing our ads in the side bar, other than frantically reloading the site's front page.

And I've done that.

Then I realized, *maybe the "reduced ads" privilege is interfering*, so I opened up an anonymous browser window and did the same thing without being logged in.

Same thing.

Not once have I seen any of our community ads in the side bar.

What's up?

Comment: Wouldn't this be better fit for Meta.SE?

Comment: @Phrancis shouldn't matter, AFAIK devs are actively monitoring [meta-tag:bug] posts ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just found out, [they aren't live yet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273255/please-dont-stretch-the-old-community-ads#comment888056_273255):

> *@Szabolcs I'm thinking like until **mid or late February** at the moment. It'll depend a lot on how much new submissions we get. – Grace Note♦ 3 hours ago*

In the mean time...

#### Let's make more ads!!